# How do I prevent an HTTP::redirect from spoiling my subdomain when the subdomain's DocumentRoot is prefixed to the redirect's URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain

I have configured Apache to load KnowledgeTree (KT) through a subdomain.

```
# Part of http.conf file
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName knowledgetree.example.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/knowledgetree
</VirtualHost>
```

When I enter `knowledgetree.example.com` into the browser, I am supposed to see KT's login page.

Instead, I end up at `knowledgetree.example.com/knowledgetree/login.php` and get the message:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /knowledgetree/login.php was not found on this
>   server.

In light of the URL where I end up, the error message is understandable because there is not another knowledgetree folder inside the htdocs/knowledgetree folder.

When I go to `example.com/knowledgetree`, everything works as expected. The index.html file calls the control.php file in the same folder. If the control.php file sees that a login is necessary, it redirects to login.php (which is also in the same folder). Perfetct.

Unfortunately, control.php somehow prefixes 'login.php' with 'knowledgetree/' and spoils everything when knowledgetree.example.com is requested.

Is it possible to configure Apache to get around this or is it necessary to make a change in KT's source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the knowledgetree database, in the config_settings table, change the value of rootUrl to an empty string and restart Apache.

Changing the values in config.ini has no effect. It is only used during setup.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this requires a change in the KnowledgeTree `config.ini` - see [here](http://docs.knowledgetree.com/manuals/ag/knowledgetree_config_ini.html).

Inside the `[KnowledgeTree]` section, set:

```
rootUrl = /
```